# php empty post array with file upload

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>Add video</h3>
        <div class="field_wrap">
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field_wrap">
        <p>Video</p>
        <input name="video" type="file" />
        </div>
        <p><button>Add</button></p>
</form>
```

This is the form I use to upload a video file and a title, so when I DON'T upload a file the $_POST variable is filled with form data, but If I upload a file the $_POST variable is empty, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong spot, try looking in `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><button>Add</button></p>
```

should be

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></p>
```

Using this all the post data is accessible as

`$_POST` and file data with `$_FILES`